# how to calculate all the modes of a array in swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift, math

The code I am using now only gives one mode, but wont give both if there are 2 modes.

```
func Mode() -> Float {
    var occurances: [Int: Int] = [:]
    for number in array {
        if var value = occurances[number] {
            occurances[number] = value + 1
            } else {
                occurances[number] = 1
            }
        }
    var highestKeyPair: (key: Int, value: Int) = (0,0)
    for (key,value) in occurances {
        highestKeyPair = (value > highestKeyPair.value) ? (key,value): highestKeyPair
    }
    let mode = highestKeyPair.key
    return Float(mode)
}
```

Comment: First, I recommend you break this down. Extract out the first part that computes `occurances`, into a function. Perhaps `countOccurences`. Then worry about how to find the top 2 values in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your function used an `array` variable, accessed from the global scope. This is very limited, so I moved these methods into an extension of Array. This way, these methods can be called on any Array, with any compatible element type.
2. I made all of this generic.
3. I extracted the first 8 lines of your function, into its own `countOccurrences()` method. I re-implemented it using [`Array.reduce(into:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce) and [`Dictionary.subscript(_:default)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript)

Here is how I implemented this:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func countOccurrences() -> [Element: Int] {
        return self.reduce(into: [:]) { (occurences, element) in occurences[element, default: 0] += 1}
    }

    func mode() -> [Element] {
        // Keeps track of the fist mode's num occurences.
        // Every other element with the same number of occurences is also a mode.
        var firstModeNumOccurences: Int? = nil

        let modes = countOccurrences()
            .sorted { pairA, pairB in pairA.value > pairB.value } // sorting in descending order of num occurences
            .lazy
            .prefix(while:) { (element, numOccurences) in  // Take all elements with the same num occurences
                if firstModeNumOccurences == nil { firstModeNumOccurences = numOccurences }
                return numOccurences == firstModeNumOccurences
            }
            .map { (element, _) in element } // keep only the elements, not their counts

        return Array(modes)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done, but I suspect Generics will leave the OP, and most beginning to intermediate Swift developers, lost. (Except those that are familiar with the concept from other languages.)

Comment: Yeah, but the same could be said for extensions, closures, functional programming styles, etc. That's why I'm responsive in the comments to address what comes up.

Comment: I'd suggest first a narrowly focused answer that addresses the question with the minimum of advanced topics like generics, and then a "now, if we use generics we can make the function more useful for a much wider group of array types" so you show the OP and other readers the concept.